# How to remove "online accounts" from "system settings"?

Tags: online-accounts, system-settings

I uninstalled "Unity" and use "Gnome Shell" instead, but the new "online accounts" was still in the "system settings" menu. How can I **completely** remove it?

I tried the command below but it doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove unity-lens-shopping account-plugin-aim account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google account-plugin-icons account-plugin-identica account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-twitter account-plugin-windows-live account-plugin-yahoo gnome-online-accounts
```

Comment: Good question.. it's a known bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1040193 I don't know how to get rid of it though.

Comment: @user19192 I've just switched to KDE after that(removed both Gnome Classic and Gnome Shell.)and luckily everything goes well.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove the option in gnome-control-center simply execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-control-center-signon
```

And you will see online accounts disappear from system settings (if you're using Unity).

Comment: NB If you've switched from Unity to GNOME and accounts added in Unity aren't showing up, this will purge them so you can re-add in GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove just the icon, without affecting anything:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-credentials-panel.desktop /usr/share/applications/ gnome-credentials-panel.desktop.old
```

Or, you can remove the package that is responsible for it

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center-signon
```